# Geany run python script with non-english path

Tags: python, geany

I'm using Geany for writing small Python scripts. Unfortunately, when I try to run a script located in a non-english folder or that has a non-english name, Geany gives errors such as 
`Could not find terminal cmd.exe /Q /C %c` 
or 
`CreateProcess failed. The directory name is invalid`.

With english path script runs ok.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: This is a bug in the Geany software, I suppose. Please consider filing a bug report or opening an issue, writing to the mailing list so that Geany developers can see this.

Comment: I found a similar isuue here: https://github.com/geany/geany/pull/809. But I don't think it has been solved already.

Comment: If you have not done already, I suppose you open an issue with a very detailed description of how to create the error. I expect it to help the project. You can open this issue here: https://github.com/geany/geany/issues but first, you would need to register on github for free.